# understanding structs and pointers and typedefs

Tags: c, pointers, struct

i would like to understand when creating a pointer to a struct is it necessary to declare a typedef struct declaration of this nature:

what i mean is

```
typedef struct _something{
   int okay; 
}blah;

typedef struct _something *finger;
```

what is the reason that it is declared in this way , why not just declare a pointer this way

```
blah *arm;
```

so if somebody can help me understand this and which is used in which case and why and its advantages?

Comment: @MM. The first typedef already took care of that. The second typedef just hides a pointer. The question seems to be about the second one.

Comment: You can use `blah *arm;`. Where is the reference that says only the first usage is correct?

Answer (score 0):

When using `typedef struct _something`, it means that each time you write `_something` it's as if your are writing `struct _something`. The typedef command just tells to replace what is written. So in other words, it avoids you to write `struct _something`.

Hoping it helps